# get response when i call the post method

Tags: android, post, android-volley

i want to be able to deal with response i'm receiving when i call the post method, i tested the post method in postman and it works fine and returns the following:

```
 [
{
    "messagetitle": "success",
    "response": {
        "tblRegisteredUsers_UserPKID": 2013,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_UserName": "hi",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Password": "hi",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_FirstName": "ahmed",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_SecondName": "mahmoud\n",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_LastName": "jallad",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Country": "أردني",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_City": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Gender": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_BirthDate": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Education": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Job": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_HomePhone": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_MobileNumber": "656",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_FaxNumber": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Email": "gmail",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_HowYouKnowUS": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Nationality": "أردني",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Active": false,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_PayType": "Knet",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_photo": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_DraftInfo": "Knet",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_AccountStates": "pending",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_registrationDate": "2017-12-08T15:21:47",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_nickName": "jallad93",
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Activeby_FKID": -1,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_ActivationDate": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Year": 1,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_ActivebyPayment": false,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_intensified": false,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Shiping_Address": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_intensified_Status": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_ReactivationDateTime": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_ActivebyPayment_Intensive": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_ActivationDate_IntensiveChange": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Installment": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_InstallmentActivationDate": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Installment_ActivePayment": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Hide": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Hide_User_FK_ID": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Hide_DateTime": null,
        "tblRegisteredUsers_Renew_Datetime": null
    }
}
```

]
other wise i get this response as follows if the login info is inncorect:

```
 [
{
    "messagetitle": "username or password is incorrect",
    "response": null
}
```

]
i want to be able to check if the login in is success the users signs in and all his info stored in variables, here is my android code:

```
 signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignIn.this);
                String URL = "http://localhost/WebApplication7/api/login";
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
               // jsonBody.put("tblRegisteredUsers_nickName", username.getText().toString().trim());
                jsonBody.put("tblRegisteredUsers_UserName", username.getText().toString().trim());
                jsonBody.put("tblRegisteredUsers_Password", password.getText().toString().trim());



                final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (response.equals("username or password is incorrect")) {
                            //login authenticated. Start the next activity of your app
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registered successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            //login failed. prompt to re-enter the credentials
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Failed to log In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                    }
                })

                {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString;
                        String json = null;
                        try {
                            json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        responseString = String.valueOf(json).trim();

                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

    }
```

what i get in the response is a string with all the information, and i always get to failed to login. it treats the response as one string. a lot of posts talk about jsonarrayrequest but i don't know how to implement it in my case

Comment: please share your whole response

Comment: Make a Model class and define setter and getter Method for every value field which you want to parse. and Save all that value after after parsing it. Login status you can save inside SharedPreference to check weather user is Already get value or not. Do let me know if you have any issue to fix this.

Comment: i already have class called User, but how can i access each element in the string https://stackoverflow.com/users/7155497/nihal-softy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Response model class with variable and it's `SerializedName` then use `Gson` library to parse your response directly into model class like the following :-

```
public class ResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("tblRegisteredUsers_UserName")
    private String userName;

    @SerializedName("tblRegisteredUsers_Password")
    private String password;

     public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    }


ResponseModel responseModel = new Gson().fromJson(response, ResponseModel.class);
```

Where response will be in the String and you will derive responseModel object of the class from which you can access all the variable that is coming from back-end.

Comment: thank but can you explain more https://stackoverflow.com/users/9102978/rudrik-patel

Comment: You are getting the success response in string with all the field when pass valid credential, Right?

Comment: Create a ResponseModel class and inside the class you can define the variable like this:-
@SerializedName("tblRegisteredUsers_UserPKID")
private String userPkId; etc...
With get() and set() method.

You can access all the variable via get method after parsing the string response.

Comment: let me try it and get back to you

Comment: i just generated pojo, now i have all the variables defined, how can i access and set each element in the string responsehttps://stackoverflow.com/users/9102978/rudrik-patel

Comment: YourModel yourModel = new Gson().fromJson(response, YourModel.class);
Parse your string using this.

Comment: Unhandled exception com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
          com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

Comment: You are on the right track. This is the parsing error, you have to customize your POJO class depend upon the response you are getting from the back-end. [ ] in the response causing the problem here.

Comment: i deleted [] but still gives the same errorhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/9102978/rudrik-patel

Comment: any suggestions ??

Comment: I have mock this response and it is working fine here.  Make sure that you are parsing Object instead of Array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9102978/rudrik-patel no uts working, thanks my dear

Comment: how if i want to store all the array element in another arraylist and fetch a listview

Comment: Didn't understand your question fully but I guess Just make a copy of the derived arraylist.